# How to hide tabs based on roles defined in attributes in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, roles

In a default install of a MVC3 website tabs are created in the top left. I would like to hide/show these tabs based on whether the current user would have access to the index ViewResult. The allowed roles to the ViewResult are defined by attributes. Is there any way of getting the list of roles for a ViewResult?

Comment: Your question is not well explained, can you ask normally please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are asking (sorry, wasn't clear exactly to me) about conditional showing of HTML elements based on roles, you *could* do something like this:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Do Some Action", "DoAction", "SomeController")
}
```

If that isn't what you're asking, let me know.

---

**Follow-up based on your comment:**

Your question interests me and I did a little poking around and found that Vivien Chevallier has an interesting idea [here](http://www.vivienchevallier.com/Articles/create-an-authorized-action-link-extension-for-aspnet-mvc-3) which essentially lets you write something like so:

`@Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("The Privilege Zone", "ThePrivilegeZone", "Home", true)`

in your View and then this check the controller action and either renders a link or doesn't.

In his controller example, you've got an action like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult ThePrivilegeZone()
{
    return View();
}
```

(I guess the key point here is that your View doesn't know squat about "Administrators" and relies upon the extension code to do the heavy lifting here:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkAuthorized(
   this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
   string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, 
   RouteValueDictionary routeValues, 
   IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes, bool showActionLinkAsDisabled)
{
   if (htmlHelper.ActionAuthorized(actionName, controllerName))
   {
      return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
         linkText, 
         actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
   }
   else
   {
      if (showActionLinkAsDisabled)
      {
         TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
         tagBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;
         return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
      }
      else
      {
         return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
      }
   }
}
```

Rather than cut/paste all of that code here, you can take a look at it and see the example application he's got for that.  I think what's particularly interesting to this approach is that the view *could* display that PrivilegeZone link but knows only that something else will determine whether that's the case.  So, assuming that you got new requirements to only allow folks who were "Administrators" or "Owners" to have access to the link, you could modify the controller action accordingly and not touch the view code.  Interesting idea, at least to me.

Comment: Sorry for the badly written question. This is almost what I'm looking for, except rather than declaring a role such as administrators is it possible to get a list of roles that have been given access to an action via the actions attributes? That way I can set the roles in an attribute and the links will automatically be displayed or not.

Comment: the code discards the `htmlAttributes` when `showActionLinkAsDisabled` is set to `true`

Comment: @twnaing add the line `tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);` before the `return` statement.

Comment: And it should really return an empty `a` rather than a `span` so it matches the expected formatting (particularly in a nav menu of links)